# How can pass parameters to a flash Movie in Delphi 2010?

Tags: flash, delphi, parameters, delphi-2010, shockwave

I have imported the ShockWave flash Activex Control in my Delphi project. I can manipulate All the properties of a Flash movie file. But I need to define my own Parameters in the my own Flash file and Manipulate those parameters in the Delphi project. I know that passing parameters to a flash file is possible in the HTML script. But my project is a desktop application and i can't use it.

Is it possible to get a handle to the defined parameter of a flash file in the Delphi project? 
in fact All i need is passing parameter to flash file in the Delphi project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The imported "TShockWaveFlash" component wrapper for "Flash10e.ocx" in my system (D2007) accepts parameters with the "FlashVars" property.

```
ShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars := 'param1=value1&param2=value2';
```

And there's a 'SetVariable' method.

```
ShockwaveFlash1.SetVariable('param', 'value');
```